# Join and search with a different foreign_key?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, foreign-keys

I got following model:

```
class Coaching < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :coach, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'coach_id'
  ...
end
```

Now I want to search for lastnames of both, users and coaches.

I tried:

`Coaching.joins(:users, :coaches).where('users.lastname LIKE :search', search: "%#{params[:search]}%")`

`Coaching.joins(:users, :coaches).where('users.lastname LIKE :search OR coaches.lastname LIKE :search', search: "%#{params[:search]}%")`

First attempt only returns users, second attempt throws an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'coaches.nachname' in 'where clause'
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `Coaching.joins(:users, :coaches).where('users.lastname LIKE :search OR coaches.lastname LIKE :search', search: "%#{params[:search]}%")`

Comment: That was a typo, sorry.

Comment: Please paste your code what you are trying to do

Comment: `Coaching.joins(:user, :coach).where('users.lastname LIKE :search OR coaches.lastname LIKE :search', search: "%#{params[:search]}%")` try this

Comment: That is the exact same code I'm using (after I edited the question)

Comment: check the code properly

Comment: I did copy paste your suggestion twice, both times the same error as before

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
Coaching.joins(:user, :coach).where("users.lastname LIKE :search OR coaches_coachings.lastname LIKE :search", search: "%#{params[:search]}%")
```

Rails called the `:coach` join `coaches_coachings` for some reason which I saw in the logs so I replaced `coaches` with `coaches_coachings` and everything works like charm!